# Subselect Package R - The covariance/total matrix supplied is not symmetric?

Tags: r, regression, logistic, subset

I was trying out the Subselect R package to see how it worked and if it would be useful for a logistic regression problem I'm working on.  [Link](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/subselect/vignettes/subselect.pdf) to the package.

I decided I would follow Example 4 on page 28 to see if I could perform the Anneal function on the glm I previously fit to my data.  I used the helper function, glmHmat, to extract the required matrices in the same way sa done in example 4.

```
Fullmodel<-glm(G,family=binomial,data)
Hmat <- glmHmat(Fullmodel)
```

I then tried the anneal function and got the following error.

```
test<-anneal(Hmat$mat,1,10,H=Hmat$H,r=1,nsol=10,criterion = "Wald")
```

Yet, I got this error.

```
Error in validmat(mat, p, tolval, tolsym, allowsingular = FALSE, algorithm) : 

 The covariance/total matrix supplied is not symmetric.
  Symmetric entries differ by up to 1.02445483207703e-07.
```

So, I thought I would test if this were true:

```
isSymmetric(Hmat$mat,tol=1e-09)
[1] TRUE
isSymmetric(Hmat$H,tol=1e-09)
[1] TRUE
```

So I can't make heads or tails of this error message.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

So, I found something that worked.  An argument of the anneal function is tolsym which allows one to specify the symmetric tolerance.  So, I added this argument as follows:

```
test<-anneal(Hmat$mat,1,10,H=Hmat$H,r=1,nsol=10,criterion = "Wald", tolsym = 1e-6)
```

I got the following warning, but it worked successfully.

```
Warning message:
In validmat(mat, p, tolval, tolsym, allowsingular = FALSE, algorithm) : 
The covariance/total matrix supplied was slightly asymmetric: 
symmetric entries differed by up to 1.02445483207703e-07.
(less than the 'tolsym' parameter).
It has been replaced by its symmetric part.
```

Strange, indeed.